# Preventing fgets from deleting first line

Tags: matlab, file-io, fgets

I'm opening a file, reading the first line using `fgets`, using `regexp` to test what format the file is in, and if the file is in the desired format, I use `fscanf` to read the entire file.

```
fid = fopen('E:\Tick Data\Data Output\Differentformatfiles\AUU01.csv','rt'); 

% reads first line of file but seems to be deleting the line:

str = fgets(fid);

% test for pattern mm/dd/yyyy
if(regexp(str, '\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d')) 

c = fscanf(fid, '%d/%d/%d,%d:%d:%d,%f,%d,%*c');
```

Unfortunately, if the contents of my file look like:

```
20010701,08:29:30.000,95.00,29,E
20010702,08:29:30.000,95.00,68,E
20010703,08:29:30.000,95.00,5,E
20010704,08:29:30.000,95.00,40,E
20010705,08:29:30.000,95.00,72,E
```

`str` will equal `20010701,08:29:30.000,95.00,29,E`, but `c` will only equal the last 4 lines:

```
20010702,08:29:30.000,95.00,68,E
20010703,08:29:30.000,95.00,5,E
20010704,08:29:30.000,95.00,40,E
20010705,08:29:30.000,95.00,72,E
```

Is there a way to prevent `fgets` from deleting the first line? Or another function I should use?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't actually erasing it, it's just moving on to the next line. You could either use a combination of `fpos` and `fseek` to go back to the beginning of that line, but since you've already got the line stored in `str`, I would add two lines:

```
if(regexp(str, '\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d')) 
c1 = sscanf(str, '%d/%d/%d,%d:%d:%d,%f,%d,%*c'); % scan the string
c2 = fscanf(fid, '%d/%d/%d,%d:%d:%d,%f,%d,%*c'); 
c = {c1;c2}; % concatenate the cells
```

It certainly isn't the most elegant solution, but it's robust and easy to shoehorn into your existing code.

Comment: I might be overlooking something, but I don't think `fscanf(str, '%d/%d/%d,%d:%d:%d,%f,%d,%*c');` is valid syntax, since str is not a file name.

Comment: `frewind(fid);` solves the problem though, which I did find in the documentation of `fseek`.

Comment: craig meant `sscanf`. But rewind is better because you don't have to duplicate your code.

Comment: siegel and @Adam, you are correct. I copied and pasted from the original code without checking too thoroughly.